# How to make compiler give at least a warning when const is not used consistently

Tags: c++, constants, compiler-warnings

Suppose I have a code with

Test.h

```
class Test{
 public:
  int Func(const int a);
};
```

Test.cpp

```
int Test::Func(const int a){
  // some code
}
```

If I take out the const for one of them the compiler will still compiles and give zero warnings. Even when -Wall and -Wextra is enabled in GCC and  /W4 is enabled in Visual studio.

For example Test.h

```
class Test{
 public:
  int Func(int a);
};
```

Test.cpp

```
int Test::Func(const int a){
  // some code
}
```

or Test.h

```
class Test{
 public:
  int Func(const int a);
};
```

Test.cpp both compiles fine.

```
int Test::Func(int a){
  // some code
}
```

How does one enable the compiler to detect when const is not use consistently between header files and source files?

Comment: Whoops, I take it all back. See my answer.

Comment: The compiler isn't complaining because top-level consts on function parameters are not part of the function's signature, the compiler ignores them as far as matching the declaration with a definition goes.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compiler errors and warnings are printed.

Comment: I've removed my comments that were wrong. I carelessly read a `&` into the declarations, and when those functions take references the `const` matters. When they take the argument by value it doesn't.

Comment: @Praetorian Is it reasonable to expect a compiler to detect it and throw a warning? Or does it has to be relied on an external cpplint-like linter?

Comment: It is a matter of opinion. I would get annoyed by such a warning, because to me there is nothing to warn about. But some compilers can be annoying.

Comment: I agree, I don't use top level consts on function parameters, so I wouldn't want such a warning. But it all depends on whether the compiler implementer thinks adding code to warn about this is worth their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard ([dcl.fct]/5)

> All declarations for a function shall agree exactly in both the return type and the parameter-
>   type-list. ... After
>   determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is
>   adjusted to be “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`,” respectively. After producing the list
>   of parameter types, any top-level *cv-qualifiers* modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the
>   function type. The resulting list of transformed parameter types and the presence or absence of the ellipsis
>   or a function parameter pack is the function’s *parameter-type-list.*

So two declarations (note: a definition is a declaration) can agree even though one has `const int a` and the other has `int a`: the top-level `const` is ignored when matching declarations.

However, top-level `const` matters in the definition. If the parameter is `const int a`, then the function body cannot modify `a`. It actually makes some sense to omit `const` in the header and include it in the definition, since the caller does not need to know that a parameter passed by value is not modified (it is an implementation detail). That's probably the reason why there isn't a warning for it. (It would be stranger to have `const` in the header and no `const` in the definition---maybe there should be a warning for that...)

Comment: interesting perspective on hiding the implementation detail, but I would argue that it's still better to put the const in the header because internal people who is implementing the class will still read the header

Comment: @user3667089 I don't understand your point. Yes, they'll read the header, but the presence or absence of `const` in the header is literally meaningless.

Comment: It will serve as a documentation for the developer to know that this variable isn't supposed to be changed

Comment: @user3667089 No, that's something only the implementer should decide. When you write the function body, if you want to change the parameter, you change it. If you don't want to change it, you don't change it. It makes no difference outside the function, so nobody else gets to tell you what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Those declarations and definitions are all the same! Top-level const is ignored in matching a declaration to a definition. So this combination is okay:

```
class C {
    void f(int);
};

void C::f(const int) {
}
```

because the `const` doesn't count, loosely speaking. Similarly,

```
class C {
    void f(int) {
    }
    void f(const int) {
    }
};
```

is an error because it defines the **same** function twice.

Comment: Any reference to the standard that explains it will be nice.

Comment: I get that it doesn't make a difference when the actual code is run so it shouldn't be an error, but shouldn't the compiler be able to catch this kind of behavior and throw a warning?

Comment: @user3667089 - the code is valid and its meaning is well defined. It's up to the compiler vendor whether the compiler should **issue** a warning, and apparently compiler vendors don't see this as a significant problem.